# Android metaio SDK upgrade 6.0.2 - setTexture not working

Tags: android, textures, metaio

we're upgrading the SDK from 5.5 to 6.0.2 and have an issue with the setTexture function.
Here's part of our code:

```
final String textureString = AssetsManager.getAssetPath(getApplicationContext(),
                    "models/red.jpg");

            mSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (textureString != null) {
            //Setting the Texutre to Object.
                        tempGeo.setTexture(textureString);
            //currently setTexture function returning true value but still we are not able to see the changes.
                    }
                }
            });
```

The setTexture function returns "true" and the texture path is valid. The problem is, that the texture is not updated on the 3D model. Nothing changed in the code and that code still works with 5.5.
The model is in FBX format.

Any ideas why the texture is not updated in the 6.0.2 SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we "solved" this issue. It wasn't related to the setTexture function or anything with the model.
There was another issue preventing parts of the code to work.